# Postgres RETURNING clause with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

In the following SQL, how could I make the `RETURNING` clause join to something else and return the joined row(s)? Here it only returns the row from `mytable` that was updated, but I'd like it to return that row joined to something in another table.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    status = 'A' 
FROM  (
   SELECT myid
   FROM   mytable
   WHERE  status = 'B'
   ORDER BY mycolumn
   LIMIT  100
   FOR   UPDATE
   ) sub
WHERE  mytable.myid = sub.myid
RETURNING *;
```

I could do another query from my client application, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do it from within Postgres within having to make a separate roundtrip to the DB.

Comment: The row in sub consists of one column, which is in mytable.  As written, the question is overly simplified.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Anything in the `FROM` clause is fair game for `RETURNING`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET status = 'A'
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      myid
    FROM mytable
    WHERE status = 'B'
    ORDER BY mycolumn
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE
  ) sub
  JOIN jointable j ON j.id = sub.myid
WHERE mytable.myid = sub.myid
RETURNING mytable.mycolumn, j.othercolumn
;
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387603/postgres-returning-clause-with-join-and-order? It's about the same SQL statement you've listed here, except I can't get it to follow the `ORDER BY mycolumn` in the outer `RETURNING` query. Thanks!